# Get specific data form Xapian database with Perl

Tags: perl, perl-module, xapian

I'm writing a perl script to retrieve search results from a Xapian database.

I uses the **Search::Xapian** module and tried the basic [Xapian Query Example](http://search.cpan.org/~olly/Search-Xapian-1.2.23.0/Xapian.pm). This basic program allow to make a query and get a array of results sorted by relevancy. My problem is that the  `get_data()` method return the whole datas from the document (url, filname, abstract, author, ...) mixed together as a string.

I searched in the [CPAN module](http://search.cpan.org/~olly/Search-Xapian-1.2.23.0/) for a method to get each data one by one but I didn't find it.

**Is it possible to get the filename, url, author, ... one by one to put them in a specific variable ?**

Comment: show your code that produces this output

Comment: `get_data()` is deliberately opaque to Xapian. Whatever you put in there, you get out; different languages make it easier to use different formats. JSON, YAML, TOML and XML are all feasible. `omindex` and `scriptindex` however use a _sui generis_ format which you can read by splitting on line ending then splitting on '=' to make key/value pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've not posted the code to produce this, or details of your setup. See the [simplesearch.pl](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/OLLY/Search-Xapian-1.2.23.0/examples/simplesearch.pl) example, rather than print it out, assign what you want to a variable:

```
# Display the results.
printf "%i results found.\n", $mset->get_matches_estimated();
printf "Results 1-%i:\n", $mset->size();

foreach my $m ($mset->items()) {
    printf "%i: %i%% docid=%i [%s]\n", $m->get_rank() + 1, $m->get_percent(), $m->get_docid(), $m->get_document()->get_data();
}
```